# FindChild Method with StackedWidget fails

Tags: qt, qstackedwidget

I'm using a qstackedwidget in my MainWindow class and I'm defining the widgets in another class (PageLayouts) in order to keep things seperate. But I'm doing the connections between the objects in the MainWindow class (change pages...), which fails. Basically:

```
//mainwindow.cpp
....

QSignalMapper * SM = new QSignalMapper(); 
Layouter = new PageLayouts();                 
//Instance of the class which contains the widgets 

QStackedWidget * Stack = new QStackedWidget(); 
Stack->addWidget(Layouter->getPage1());

connect(SM, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), Stack, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
SM->setMapping(Stack->widget(0)->findChild<QPushButton *>("Btn_ToPage2"), 1);

connect(Stack->widget(0)->findChild<QPushButton *>("Btn_ToPage2"), SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SM, SLOT(map()));
.... 

//Debugging says to the first connect:
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::destroyed() to QSignalMapper::_q_senderDestroyed()

//To the second:
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked(bool) to QSignalMapper::map()
```

I suppose I do not get the PushButtons via the findchild methods properly. 
So my questions are:

1. How to enter the children of the widgets within a stackedwidget?
2. Since im still making experiments with stackedwidgets, are there more elegant ways of using them?

Thanks, Sebastian

Edit 1:

Here's the code which generates Page1 in "pagelayouts.h":

```
class PageLayouts
{
QWidget * Page1;
QWidget * Page2;

public:
PageLayouts();

//Get 
QWidget * getPage1();
....
```

And the code which generates page1 in "pagelayouts.cpp":

```
PageLayouts::PageLayouts()
{
//Page1
QHBoxLayout * HL_112 = new QHBoxLayout();   
QVBoxLayout * VL_122 = new QVBoxLayout();                             

QLabel * Lbl_NamePage1 = new QLabel("Page 1");
QPushButton * Btn_ToPage2 = new QPushButton("Page 2");
QPushButton * Btn_Close1 = new QPushButton("Close");

//Assembling of Page1
VL_122->addWidget(Btn_ToPage2);
VL_122->addWidget(Btn_Close1);
HL_112->addWidget(Lbl_NamePage1);
HL_112->addLayout(VL_122);

Page1 = new QWidget();
Page1->setLayout(HL_112);

//Page2
....
}

QWidget* PageLayouts::getPage1()
{
return Page1;
}
```

You can see it's experimental code, but I'm testing qstackedwidgets for further design decisions and hope someone can solve this issue.

Comment: Could you show the piece of code where page1 and its button are created?

Comment: Ok just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing "Btn_ToPage2" as a name to `QObject::findChild()`. The name of the variable is `Btn_ToPage2`, but you are not setting an object name:

```
Btn_ToPage2->setObjectName("Btn_ToPage2");
```